# The Where clause in Row-Number() select

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have paging using Row_Number(). The statement is as follows:

```
with Data as
(
    select
        distinct Table1.SomeID,

        ROW_NUMBER() over
        (
            order by Table1.Col100 desc
        ) as RowNumber,

        Table1.Col1,
        Table2.Col2
    from
        Table1
            inner join Table2 on Table1.SomeID = Table2.SomeID
    where
        Table1.Col1 = 'abc' and Table2.Col2 = 123
)

select
    top (10) RowNumber,
    *
from
    Data
where
    RowNumber > 20
    -- and Col1 = 'abc' and Col2 = 123
```

Do I need the commented out line in the Where clause of the second select? Thanks.

Comment: Your question isnt complete, Read it to yourself and try to see if make sense. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: No you dont,the first WHERE is enough.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza How is it incomplete? What else would you need to understand this simple question?

Comment: I`m guessing people miss the first WHERE and are confused.

Comment: Of course ppl miss the first `WHERE`. That is why you could prepare a better question pointing where is the problem so we dont waste time inspecting your code. And those links will help you with some tips. BTW Mihai is correct you dont need second where., on `DATA`   the rows are already filter by `COL1` and `COL2`

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Understood. Thanks.

Comment: Using `top` without `order by` does not guarantee any particular order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you do not need it in the second select, the first select makes sure that only information meeting the 'abc' '123' criteria are included.